# Access iPhone from Windows

Tags: iphone, c++

I've seen a couple programs running in Windows that could access the iPhone and iTouch with access to the photo library and music.  What APIs are used for this kind of development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)). It's a service discovery protocol by Apple and there is a windows implementation [available](http://support.apple.com/downloads/Bonjour_for_Windows). Apple has released various samples that you can use as a starting point. Checkout this sample game [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/WiTap/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007321) to get started. And for a broader overview, this [tutorial](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) might be good. Once you discover a network device or machine, you can use whatever data format is convenient such as XML, JSON, home-grown, or binary.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides an [iTunes COM SDK](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/05/20/itunes-com-for-windows-sdk-now-in-adc.aspx) that will allow you to pull data directly from iTunes.  Although I haven't used it, this may be what you are looking for.  I imagine you would need to have the iPhone sync'd with iTunes before you could access information from it - but again I'm not sure.

Here is an older link that will redirect you properly through Apple's site: http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to do, but you might want to look into Bonjour, Apple's implementation of zeroconf networking. You can launch an app on the iPhone which provides a service, which a Windows app can then connect to. I've seen this used to transfer files to/from the iPhone.

http://www.tuaw.com/2007/11/07/iphone-coding-bonjour-wrapper-simplifies-iphone-implementation/

and

http://www.tuaw.com/2007/10/23/send-files-directly-from-iphone-to-another/

seem like good places to start.