# Sending image data from iPhone/iPad to Windows PC over wifi

Tags: iphone, tcp, bluetooth, wifi

I'm writing an iPhone/iPad program where I can capture an image, draw something on the image(e.g a line), and send it to a PC (e.g WinXP) in real time. To send the image data to a PC, I'm considering bluetooth and wifi but here's what I found:

1. Bluetooth - IMPOSSIBLE, no API
2. Wifi TCP/IP - (i) [Bonjour NSStream(XCode) and GCDAsyncSocket(C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809848/asycnsocket-not-connecting-to-tcp-serial-port-over-wifi?rq=1) (ii) [Bonjour NSStream(XCode) and Bonjour Windows (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010123/access-iphone-from-windows?rq=1)
3. Wifi UDP - [Bonjour NSStream(XCode) and MFC's CAsyncSocket(C++)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16581/Sending-Receiving-UDP-Datagrams-with-MFC-s-CAsyncS)

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO: Use a TCP server on your PC and a TCP client app (FastSocket https://github.com/dreese/fast-socket) and over the WiFi (either LAN or WLAN), you should be able to send the image over the network. Also, please see this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server